# Make and run, beginsWithU function in prelude

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

How can i define, run this function in prelude,

```
let beginsWithU (c:_) = c == 'u' || c == 'U'
   beginsWithU _ = False
```

Line number 2, gives `parse error on input ‘=’`. I cannot use let again since it will override the pattern in line 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "run this function in prelude" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to run it inside ghci.
You can use multiline input for this, the commands are `:{` to start it and `:}` to end it.

Here's the example

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let beginsWithU (c:_) = c == 'u' || c == 'U'
Prelude|     beginsWithU _ = False
Prelude| :}
Prelude> beginsWithU "umbrella"
True
Prelude> beginsWithU "mbrella"
False
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i define, run this function in prelude

You cannot define and run a function in prelude. Prelude is a standard module which comes along with the base package which is shipped with ghc.

Assuming that you want to define and run the code in `ghci`, this is what you have to do:

```
λ> let beginsWithU (c:_) = c == 'u' || c == 'U'; beginsWithU _ = False
λ> beginsWithU "UHello"
True
```